# I want to automate excel to search and get result from a website

Tags: excel, vba, web-crawler

I have over 1,000 search items to search from a website. I want to use VBA to automate the search and copy the response into excel columns (i.e. col A1 - search item 1, *col B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, and H1* - result 1, then search item 2 start on the next line, A2....H2). I have tried different formulas in excel but none seems to give desired outcome. Help a rookie.

Comment: These resources will help: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 46 - Querying Web Pages using Query Tables](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=ZrPEAljQjRM&index=51&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) And
[Excel VBA Introduction Part 47 - Browsing to Websites and Scraping a Web Page](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=dShR33CdlY8&index=52&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
[Excel VBA Introduction Part 48 - Web Scraping Across Multiple Pages](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=sGw6r5GVA5g&index=53&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to the links TinMan posted for you in his comment.
Here is a solution in VBA. Your search items must be placed in column A from row 2 in the Excel sheet you start the macro from:

```
Sub DrugDetails()
  Const baseUrl = "https://web22.gov.mb.ca/eFormulary/drugDetails.aspx?din="
  Dim urlParam As String
  Dim result As String
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim currentRow As Long
  Dim currentCol As Long
  Dim xhr As Object
  Dim htmlDoc As Object
  Dim nodeHtmlTableRows As Object
  Dim currentHtmlTableRow As Long
  Dim currentLink As String
  Dim currentLinkText As String
  
  Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("HtmlFile")
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  
  If lastRow > 1 Then
    For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
      currentCol = 2
      urlParam = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1))
      With xhr
        .Open "GET", baseUrl & urlParam, False
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
          htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
          ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1), Address:=baseUrl & urlParam, TextToDisplay:=ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
          Set nodeHtmlTableRows = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
          For currentHtmlTableRow = 0 To nodeHtmlTableRows.Length - 1
            Select Case currentHtmlTableRow
              Case 2 To 5
                ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol) = Trim(nodeHtmlTableRows(currentHtmlTableRow).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext)
                currentCol = currentCol + 1
              Case 6 To 8
                If nodeHtmlTableRows(currentHtmlTableRow).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a").Length Then
                  currentLink = nodeHtmlTableRows(currentHtmlTableRow).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
                  currentLinkText = nodeHtmlTableRows(currentHtmlTableRow).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innertext
                  If InStr(1, currentLink, "about:") > 0 Then
                    currentLink = Replace(currentLink, "about:", "https://web22.gov.mb.ca/eFormulary/")
                  End If
                  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol), Address:=currentLink, TextToDisplay:=currentLinkText
                  currentCol = currentCol + 1
                Else
                  ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol) = Trim(nodeHtmlTableRows(currentHtmlTableRow).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext)
                  currentCol = currentCol + 1
                End If
            End Select
          Next currentHtmlTableRow
        Else
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol) = "Page not loaded"
        End If
      End With
    Next currentRow
  Else
    MsgBox "No data in column A"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not a visionary. I only programmed it based on the number you gave as an example. For testing, I took the other numbers behind one of the links. If you copied your numbers from the page, you may have copied the trailing spaces. That also happened to me. The macro expects clean numbers. You have to format the cells in Excel as text, because the numbers can also have leading zeros. If you have numbers that show another table, the macro will not work. Just saying "It doesn't work in row x" is not very helpful. What is the number for the url which causes the error?

Comment: Does it work now? I had made a request on Google, to get access to the link you posted for more search items.

Comment: 80001869, 80007498, 00001082 and so on are not valid Drug Identification Numbers.